# Stretching Google Maps

Tags: jquery

I wanted to make something, like I call it - map stretching. It seems like giving element a class, and so on, but I think, that this is not the most appropriate way.

I saw very interesting interpretation of stretching google maps in ios Foursquare, when you touch and slide your finger down when seeing any venue info and it's map. Center keeps remaining in is place, and height grows.

So far, I did it like this:

```
$('#map_canvas').click(function() {
    if($( '#content #map_canvas' ).hasClass('small_map')){
        $( '#content #meta' ).hide();
        $( '#content #description' ).hide();
        $( '#content .social' ).hide();

        $( '#content #map_canvas' ).removeClass('small_map');
        $( '#content #map_canvas' ).addClass('large_map');
    }else {
        $( '#content #meta' ).show();
        $( '#content #description' ).show();
        $( '#content .social' ).show();

        $( '#content #map_canvas' ).removeClass('large_map');
        $( '#content #map_canvas' ).addClass('small_map');
    }
    initialize();   
});
```

...by clicking on map, hiding everything, and stretching the map height. But I don't like that I have to call initialize(); function over and over, to keep map center in center.

Could someone share your ideas? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setCenter` rather than re-initializing the entire map:

```
map.setCenter( pos );
```

Where `map` is a reference to your google map, and `pos` is a position, just as you've probably set one when setting up the map in the first place. Just make sure that those two are available outside of your `initialize` script.